# Установил диапазон от 5 до 20 но выпало 23, почему?

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Установил диапазон от 5 до 20 но выпало 23, как такое может быть ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может я что-то не так делаю ?

Comment: Ну может считаете неправильно, так как верхняя граница `5 + (1 * 20)` будет `25`-ти равна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Случайное число из диапазона `[min, max]`, на Java.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```